# Represent postal addresses in Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

How would one represent postal addresses in Cloud Spanner so that they are consistent with the proto defined in [postal_address.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/postal_address.proto)? I want to read and write the from/to the database using Go.

Initially, I represented the postal address as a single Address column of type STRING in Spanner. I did this by concatenating all of the fields defined in the proto file. This works decently well for write operations.

However, when I wanted to *read* from the database, I was obviously not able to extract these specific fields that were concatenated as a string. I need the fields because I need to populate a struct with a PostalAddress field.

What would be the best way to represent a postal address of this nature? I could represent each field as a separate column, but this seems far too involved and would mean I would have to write far more complex queries to get a single address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your use case is a good fit for JSON type which Cloud Spanner now supports. You should be able to create a corresponding JSON representation for the [postal_address.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/postal_address.proto) that you have mentioned. Please see https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/working-with-json for how-to as well as examples of how to query individual fields during reads.